# Trying to convert Unix Epoch time into UTC localized date/time string

Tags: javascript, localization, locale, unix-timestamp

My goal is to convert an integer expressing the Unix Epoch time (or the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970) into a localized time for the UTC (or GMT) time-zone.

So I have this method:

```
function formatDateTimeFromTicks(nTicks)
{
    //'nTicks' = number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970
    //RETURN:
    //      = Formatted date/time
    return new Date(nTicks).toLocaleString();
}
```

As an example I'm using the value of `1442004135000`, which should give me `‎9‎/‎11‎/‎2015‎ 8‎:‎42‎:‎15‎ ‎PM` for my locale ([here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)'s where you can check), but my method:

```
alert(formatDateTimeFromTicks(1442004135000));
```

gives me `‎‎9‎/‎11‎/‎2015‎ ‎1‎:‎42‎:‎15‎ ‎PM`.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: what's your locale settings? I'm getting 8:42pm, with my timezone set to CEST. To be precise, I get "11 septembre 2015 22:42:15 UTC+2"

Comment: @Touffy: The timezone in this case should not matter, because I need it to display time for UTC (or Greenwich) time zone. The locale should be used only to format date/time itself. In other words it should not be converting anything.

Comment: Right, sorry, you want UTC. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: It feels like `new Date(nTicks)` does the conversion into local time. I'm not sure why though?

Comment: You can ask for new Date().toUTCString() but you can't get that in a locale format natively.

Comment: @Touffy: You see, if I do `new Date(2015, 9 - 1, 11, 20, 42, 15, 0).toLocaleString()` it gives me `9‎/‎11‎/‎2015‎ ‎8‎:‎42‎:‎15‎ ‎PM`, which is what I want (for this locale). That's why I'm thinking that `new Date(nTicks)` somehow does some sort of a conversion. I just don't understand why?

Comment: Ah, yes, if you give it date and time arguments without the timezone offset, it will use the local timezone by default, not zero. I suppose you could substract the offset (times 60000) from your Unix timestamp, then use toLocaleString() to show the localized UTC.

Answer (score 0):

The native Date object won't be enough, as even in the best case it doesn't give you a UTC *and* locale string. I strongly suggest you use the excellent [moment](http://momentjs.com) library to have reliable behavior across all platforms.

To display nice localized UTC in French:

```
moment(1442004135000).utc().locale('fr').format('LLLL')
```

=> "vendredi 11 septembre 2015 20:42"

Comment: Thank you, but this is a question about "pure" JavaScript. I don't want to "drag" a whole library into my page just to display one date. This is exactly the reason why Internet is so bloated these days!

Comment: I am not in the habit of dragging libraries into my answers (in particular I kinda hate seeing jQuery everywhere) but in this case the native object just sucks, and moment is really good. If you want to achieve the same result using native Dates, you'd have to guess which part of the localized output is the hour, then change that to correct for timezone.